# Why is a trailing comma needed here to pass a list in an *args parameter?

Tags: python, syntax, parameter-passing

I was attempting to use the `threading` package in Python 3 and ran into a situation about trailing commas I don't understand.

##### Here is the code, **without a comma**:

```py
import threading

def thread_func(my_list):
    print(my_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_func, args=(test_list))  # WITHOUT comma
    my_thread.start()
```

which gives this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: thread_func() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

As you can see, Python tried to "unravel" the list and pass it as if each element were an argument.

##### If I **add a comma** to the args value, it works correctly:

```py
import threading

def thread_func(my_list):
    print(my_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_func, args=(test_list,))  # WITH comma
    my_thread.start()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Normally, if I wanted to pass a list as an argument to this function, I would use the structure `thread_func(test_list)` and [it would work fine](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_passing_list.asp). Why is a trailing comma needed here?

Comment: `(anything) === anything`,  however `[anything]` is always a list ... if you add a trailing comma than `(anything,)` becomes a tuple with the first thing as the thing

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't comprehend what you're trying to communicate. Perhaps you could expound on your thoughts in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the comma makes the tuple, or so the saying goes.

`(1)` is just grouping parens, but `(1, )` is a tuple with one int. In this case under the hood the thread initializer is unpacking args, so without the comma it's unpacking test list, basically `test_func(*test_list)` but with the comma it unpacks the tuple, and everything works.

Comment: Ahh I see, the unpacking args explanation was what I wasn't understanding (and wasn't gleaning from other questions). Thank you for the help!